# How to check in ruby if an string contains any of an array of strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have an array of strings `a`, and I want to check if another long string `b` contains any of the strings in the array

```
a = ['key','words','to', 'check']
b = "this is a long string"
```

What different options do I have to accomplish this?

For example this seems to work

```
not a.select { |x| b.include? x }.empty?
```

But it returns a negative response, thats why I had `not`, any other ideas or differents ways?

Comment: Be careful when using the operators `and`, `or` and `not` instead of `&&`, `||` and `!` because they have lower precedence than assignment operators.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There you go using [#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

```
a = ['key','words','to', 'check']
b = "this is a long string"
a.any? { |s| b.include? s }
```

Or something like using [`::union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union). But as per the need, you might need to change the regex, to some extent it can be done. If not, then I will go with above one.

```
a = ['key','words','to', 'check'] 
Regexp.union a
# => /key|words|to|check/ 
b = "this is a long string"
Regexp.union(a) === b # => false
```

Comment: I think the regex will be significantly faster

Comment: @DGM - I would think quite the opposite - regex will probably significantly slower than `include?`...

Comment: @DGM Go ahead and benchmark it. In general, string matches are faster than regular expressions, but there are always edge cases. YMMV.

Comment: In this case, it's not bad, but if the string is 100k long, and the list of words in the hundreds, you have a n*m problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Scan and Flatten

There are a number of ways to do what you want, but I like to program for clarity of purpose even when it's a little more verbose. The way that groks best to me is to scan the string for each member of the array, and then see if the flattened result has any members. For example:

```
a = ['key','words','to', 'check']
b = "this is a long string"
a.map { |word| b.scan /#{word}/ }.flatten.any?
# => false

a << 'string'
a.map { |word| b.scan /#{word}/ }.flatten.any?
# => true
```

The reason this works is that scan returns an array of matches, such as:

```
=> [[], [], [], [], ["string"]]
```

[Array#flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-flatten) ensures that the empty nested arrays are removed, so that [Enumerable#any?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) behaves the way you'd expect. To see why you need #flatten, consider the following:

```
[[], [], [], []].any?
# => true
[[], [], [], []].flatten.any?
# => false
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thanks for a great suggestion. While I like #flat_map, and it makes the chain a little shorter, I often prefer composable chains for clarity and ease of debugging. Also, I believe #flat_map was introduced in 1.9.2, so it may not be useful for anyone on a legacy Ruby. While I haven't tested it, I'm pretty sure my examples will work on anything back to 1.8.6 or so, which hopefully makes it useful to a wider audience. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the array intersection ([#&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-26)) method:

```
a = ['key','words','to', 'check']
b = "this is a long string"
shared = a & b.gsub(/[.!?,'"]/, "").split(/\s/)
```

Which would return an array containing all the shared characters.